# problems installing Theano with Anaconda3 (Python version 3.6)

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda, theano

I have tried to install `theano` as indicated in the instruction 
typing `pip install theano` on the Anaconda prompt
I have encountered the following issue.

It gave me these errors:

```
(base) C:\Users >pip install theano
Collecting theano
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line
215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py",
line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, i
n build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line
380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line
554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", l
ine 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 465, i
n find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 423, i
n find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 568, i
n _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 683, i
n _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 811, i
n get_page
    inst = cls(resp.content, resp.url, resp.headers)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 731, i
n __init__
    namespaceHTMLElements=False,
TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'
```

what can I do ??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case updating pip worked.

```
conda update pip
```